# How can I read and write to Firebase Storage from within Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I want to save a file from Cloud Functions for Firebase to Firebase Storage.

I also want to read the file from Firebase Storage to Cloud Functions for Firebase at a later time.

I couldn't find any example for the same. Can someone help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cloud Functions run in a fairly standard V8 Node.js container. So you can use the regular [Node SDK for Google Cloud Storage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node#cloud-storage-beta) to interact with your files.

A snippet of code from the link:

```
// Upload a local file to a new file to be created in your bucket.
bucket.upload('/photos/zoo/zebra.jpg', function(err, file) {
  if (!err) {
    // "zebra.jpg" is now in your bucket.
  }
});
```

But really: just go to the link, it contains a better example than I'm willing to copy/paste here.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your reply. I checked it out earlier however what I want to use is Firebase Storage rather than Google Cloud Storage. My application is still in alpha stage and I dont want to pay for its storage at this time. Firebase Storage has free 5GB plan (Spark) which is what I am currently subscribed to. However Google Cloud Storage charges for  from day 1. I am just wondering why there is no sample to put/get a file from Firebase Functions to Firebase Storage.

Comment: Firebase Storage (recently renamed "Cloud Storage for Firebase") is a client-side SDK around Google Cloud Storage. Since Cloud Functions run on the server, there is no Firebase SDK for Storage there (nor is it needed). The link I gave in my answer leads directly to a sample of accessing your files.

Comment: Can you clarify on my confusion about Google Cloud Storage pricing?
Is it free for certain limits?

Comment: When you have a Firebase project on the free/spark plan, you can use Cloud Storage for Firebase for free within the quota indicated on the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/). It doesn't matter what SDK you use to access the storage.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted answer.