# Upload images on Firebase storage using Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way that I can upload images to Firebase storage using Firebase Cloud Functions?

And if there is then how cloud functions are going to get the images to store them?

Thanks.

Comment: Cloud Functions for Firebase run on a fairly standard node environment. You can just use the gcloud Node modules to access Cloud Storage from there. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960506/how-can-i-read-and-write-to-firebase-storage-from-within-cloud-functions-for-fir/42966835#42966835) and [this example from the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#execute_intensive_tasks_in_the_cloud_instead_of_in_your_app).

Comment: Hey Frank! Can you suggest how can an image be sent to cloud functions so that the functions could store them to storage??

Comment: Why don't you just use the [Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) to send the image directly from the device to storage, and then [trigger a Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) from that.