# include access to firebase storage on nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

Is there an intention to include access to firebase storage on nodejs?  #AskFirebase

I'm trying using google-cloud but it is signed as deprecated and I'm not sure to put it in production...

Comment: There is no [node.js client for Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960506/how-can-i-read-and-write-to-firebase-storage-from-within-cloud-functions-for-fir/42966835#42966835). You should be using the regular [GCS node.js SDK](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-storage). If you're having problems with that, share the [minimum code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer.